# PHP Reload Nginx Failing

Tags: php, nginx, ssh, debian

So I am having a strange error, essentially I am trying to reload nginx via a php script.

I have coded and tried the following solution, but even it does not work.

Which is extremely strange, it should just be logging in as root and have all of the root capabilities.

When I run service nginx reload from command line as root it works perfectly.

Here is the code

```
<?php


ini_set('include_path', '/myfolder');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('1.1.1.1');
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'foobar')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('service nginx reload');

?>
```

Comment: Output: "
Reloading nginx configuration: nginx failed!
"

Comment: Does the same happen, when you login by hand and execute `service nginx reload`? I assume yes - if so, check ningx error log or syslog.

Comment: If I log in by hand and execute the command it works properly. Will check logs right now and post updates

Comment: No syslog or errors from running the script

Comment: Any updates on this? It's a very strange problem, I have even tried running this script on another server.